# How to get Multiple Months Data into Multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a sample query as shown below,

```
SELECT SUM(Test) AS TotalLastMonth
FROM Table
WHERE  date >=DATEADD(MONTH, -1, getdate())
GROUP BY InvoiceNo
```

Result:

```
    22
    12
    34
    21
    16
    10
    18
```

I am trying to retrieve multiple months data into multiple columns.Sample output

```
TotalLastMonth TotalLast6Months TotalLast12Months
10              22                   97
12              24                   57
15              30                   63
21              42                   78
25              50                   75
```

Comment: You need to provide some actual details here. Just posting random numbers with no context does not let anybody help. here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Most likely you will want to use conditional aggregation here.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation would work...

```
select 
     TotalLastMonth = sum(case when date >= dateadd(month,-1,getdate()) then Test end)
    ,TotalLast6Months = sum(case when date >= dateadd(month,-6,getdate()) then Test end)
    ,TotalLast6Months = sum(case when date >= dateadd(month,-12,getdate()) then Test end)
```

If you want whole months excluding this month, then use your `DATEADD` logic to get the first of the month, and last of the month.

```
select
     --total last month, not including this month 
     TotalLastMonth = sum(case when date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) and date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then Test end)
     --total last 6 months not including this month
    ,TotalLast6Months = sum(case when date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0) and date <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then Test end)
     --total last 12 months not including this month
    ,TotalLast6Months = sum(case when date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) and date <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) then Test end)
```